# Perforce -- generate a diff including added files?

Tags: diff, perforce

When I use "p4 diff", it ignores files that I have open for add.  Is it possible to generate a diff that includes added files as well as changed files?

Comment: Would 'p4 reconcile' work for you? http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering the [diff in Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff.html) compare the files in the client workspace to revisions in the depot, the short answer is "no".
There is no recorded history to compare to for the [added file](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/add.html) (not committed to the depot before a submit)

The longer answer would involve a script to complete the diff with the full content of the added files. (kind of like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771314/in-perforce-command-line-how-to-diff-a-file-reopened-for-add))

Answer (score 3):

This is a known missing feature of p4 diff that lots of tools dealing with Perforce have to work around.

The code review tool [Reviewboard](http://www.reviewboard.org/) comes with the  tool [post-review](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=rbtools&submit=search). It is used to create diffs for a a codereview, but it will just do a diff if you want.

It's in python, you could pull out the diff section for your own use.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to help me on cygwin:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "usage: $0 <pathSpec>"
        exit 1
fi

pathSpec=$1

doIt () {
        p4 opened "$pathSpec" | egrep "#.* - add" | while read f; do
                # figure out the workspace path
                depotPath=${f%#*}
                clientFileLine=$(p4 fstat "$depotPath" | grep clientFile)
                workspacePathWin=${clientFileLine#... clientFile }

                # diff output
                echo ==== $depotPath#1 - $workspacePathWin ====
                workspacePath=$(cygpath "$workspacePathWin")
                lineCount=$(wc -l < "$workspacePath")
                echo @@ -0,0 +1,$lineCount @@

                # the actual diff contents
                sed -e 's/^/+/' "$workspacePath"
                echo
        done
}

doIt
```

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around this issue and got my added files included in a Fisheye pre-commit review.

What I did was copy the edited files' diff hunk descriptor header. This includes one line which lists the depot and local paths - pretty straightforward - and another line with the range information, formatted as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format).

So, I added each appended each file's contents to the diff, each preceded by

```
==== //path/to/depot/file#1 - /path/to/workspace/file ====
@@ -1,1 +1,LEN @@
```

where `LEN` is the number of lines in the added file.

This worked for me; Your Mileage May Vary.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this to work, branching off Aaron's answer. Instead of

`==== //path/to/depot/file#1 - /path/to/workspace/file ====`

I used

```
--- //path/to/file [TIMESTAMP GENERATED BY NORMAL DIFF]
+++ //path/to/file [TIMESTAMP GENERATED BY NORMAL DIFF]
    @@ -1,1 +1,LEN @@
```

Then make sure to have a `+` at the beginning of each added line.

Answer (score 0):

Just p4 print the added files (I know, that's not great) - but its definitely one way to go.